# Prove by induction that $21 | 4^{n+1} + 5^{2n-1}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

The problem that I have is: Prove by induction that 21 divides 4<sup>n+1</sup> + 5<sup>2n-1</sup>

So far I have:

**Base Case:**
$n = 1$
$4^{1+1} + 5^{2-1} = 4^2 + 5^1 = 16 + 5 = 21$

**Inductive Step:**
Assume: $4^{k+1} + 5^{2k-1} = 3m$
$4^{(k+1)+1} + 5^{2(k+1)-1} = 3m$
$4^{k+2} + 5^{2k+1} = 3m$

I'm pretty sure I am far off on this one and not sure where to go.

Thanks

Comment: Why doesn't 21 appear in your inductive hypothesis?

Comment: In your 3rd step, you missed a one in the second term and where is 21 in your argument?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can proceed with the inductive step as follows:

Assume that $$21 \mid 4^{k+1}+5^{2k-1}$$which implies 
$$21\mid 25(4^{k+1}+5^{2k-1})$$ $$\Longrightarrow21\mid 25(4^{k+1})+5^{2k+1}$$
We can subtract a multiple of $21$ on the right side to obtain
$$21\mid 25(4^{k+1})+5^{2k+1}-21(4^{k+1})$$
$$\Longrightarrow 21\mid4(4^{k+1})+5^{2k+1}$$
$$\Longrightarrow 21\mid4^{k+2}+5^{2k+1}$$
$$\Longrightarrow 21\mid4^{(k+1)+1}+5^{2(k+1)-1}$$
This completes the proof.

Answer (score 5):

Consider this:

$$4^{n+2} + 5^{2n+1} = 4\cdot 4^{n+1} + (21+4)\cdot 5^{2n-1} = 21\cdot5^{2n-1}  + 4\cdot (4^{n+1}+5^{2n-1})$$